# "Следующее, на что стоит обратить внимание(?) это глаза"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Нужно ли тире перед словом *это*?
И поясните, если можно, какое здесь действует правило.

**Следующее, на что стоит обратить внимание, это глаза.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Следующее, на что стоит обратить внимание, — это глаза.**

1. [**Тире**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire) ставится перед **это, это есть, это значит, вот**, если сказуемое, выраженное существительным в именительном падеже, присоединяется посредством этих слов к подлежащему (§ 166).
   Слово *следующее* в этом предложении выступает в роли существительного и является подлежащим, поэтому и ставится тире.
   (См. [**следующий**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/222846/%D0%A1%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%94%D0%A3%D0%AE%D0%A9%D0%98%D0%99). Толковый словарь Ожегова.)
2. Запятая перед тире закрывает придаточное предложение.

*Следующее, на что следует обратить внимание, — это заявленный производителем срок службы и гарантийный срок.*

*Выбирая щенка, помните, что уравновешенный темперамент — самое необходимое качество, которым должна обладать немецкая овчарка. Следующее, на что нужно обратить внимание, — это здоровье щенков.*